# Remove duplicates from list of dicts based on item key

Tags: python, list

I have list of dicts

```
[{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-04-27'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-24'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-17'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-11'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-10'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-05'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-01-14'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-01-13'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-12-02'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-27'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-12'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-05'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-10-01'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-08-19'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-08-14'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}]
```

What I need to get is lines:

```
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13'}
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}
```

Basically only those lines when item key has changed or last element.

```
Tried to convert to list of tuples and 
seen = set()
Output = [(a, b) for a, b in version_list_tuples if (a in seen or seen.add(a))]
print(Output)
```

But got

```
[('7.0(3)I7(6)', '2020-04-27'), ('7.0(3)I4(4)', '2019-08-19')]
```

Basically first element and when next unique key. But it is not what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each dictionary in `version_list_tuples` list has 1 item, you can do this:

```
d = {[*v][0]: v[[*v][0]] for v in version_list_tuples}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13', '7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}
```

---

If you want list of dictionaries, then:

```
out = [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13'}, {'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}]
```

---

EDIT:

The line:

```
{[*v][0]: v[[*v][0]] for v in version_list_tuples}
```

is dict-comprehension. For each value `v` of list `version_list_tuples` it creates key `[*v][0]` with value `v[[*v][0]]`.

What is `[*v][0]`? It unpacks keys found in dictionary `v` into a list and then picks first key. Basically, get key from dictionary with one element.

Then `v[[*v][0]]` gets value associated with this key.

Comment: Perhaps you also want to explain what is this line `{[*v][0]: v[[*v][0]] for v in version_list_tuples}` doing?

Comment: @norok2 I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  d = {[*v][0]: v[[*v][0]] for v in version_list_tuples} - exactly what was needed

Answer (score 0):

Merge all the dictionaries (you could, if you wanted, use `functools.reduce` too, but this is arguably easier to read, and quite certainly more efficient), then "decompose" into a list of single key-value dicts:

```
>>> data = [...]  # your original data
>>> merged = {}
>>> for item in data:
...    merged.update(item)
...
>>> merged
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13', '7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}
>>> pairs = [{k: v} for (k, v) in merged.items()]
>>> pairs
[{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13'}, {'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}]
```

If you need the reverse order, i.e. the first occurrence of a key, use `for item reversed(data)` when merging:

```
>>> merged = {}
>>> for item in reversed(data):
...     merged.update(item)
...
>>> merged
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-08-19', '7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-04-27'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
def process(data):
    iter_data = iter(data)
    last_k, last_v = next(iter(next(iter_data).items()))
    for d in iter_data:
        k, v = next(iter(d.items()))
        if k != last_k:
            yield (last_k, last_v)
        last_k, last_v = k, v
    yield (last_k, last_v)
```

This does what you describe and does not rely on uniqueness of `dict` keys, meaning that it would work also for inputs where the key repeats in multiple groups, e.g.:

```
data = [{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-04-27'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-24'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-17'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-11'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-10'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-02-05'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-01-14'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2020-01-13'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-12-02'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-27'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-12'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-11-05'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-10-01'},
{'7.0(3)I7(6)': '2019-09-13'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-08-19'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-08-14'},
{'7.0(3)I4(4)': '2019-05-21'}] 


print(list(process(data)))
# [('7.0(3)I7(6)', '2019-09-13'), ('7.0(3)I4(4)', '2019-05-21')]
```

but also:

```
data2 = data * 2


print(list(process(data2)))
# [('7.0(3)I7(6)', '2019-09-13'), ('7.0(3)I4(4)', '2019-05-21'), ('7.0(3)I7(6)', '2019-09-13'), ('7.0(3)I4(4)', '2019-05-21')]
```

I suspect there is also a way to do this with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but I am not sure.